# Using a slicer to choose one column of a power Pivot table to exibit

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have a pivot table that summarizes a list of properties of many furnaces over a period of time.
Each line is a date and each column is a property.
I have dozens, and properties, would be unpractical to build a separate table for each and the charts would be not the same.
I can slice by period of time and by furnace easily with the slice/timeline tool.

The objective is to build a "slicer" that can show the distribution or evolution in time (scatter over dates or histogram of period) of one property, and be able to change the property I am looking for.
Is there a way to build a panel that given a selection, gets the data of one column of a table (or several)

Example:

[Complete table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmeg8.png)

And given a selector I could for example select P1 and then the table would be:

[Sliced table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNAEt.png)

And then, using this table as the basis for the chart, I could create a time series or histogram of the property.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the data through Power Query first (Data ribbon, Get & Transform Data), and use the Unpivot functionality to return a row for each furnace (for each date), with a "Furnace" column.

From that point the output you require becomes trivial.

Comment: There are some problems with that: 1) you may have to duplicate data if you need the unpivoted version, 2) you may not be able to use both in your report as you will not be able to link them (for some reason, PowerBI refuses to link/connect two same tables), 3) speed may not be great because the unpivoted version will have many more lines